# I have a Python data frame with 2 columns. I want to copy data from the second column into a text file. How can I do this?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dataset

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df_1  = pd.read_csv("result4.csv")

df_1.to_csv('dataset_1.txt', sep='\n', index=False)
```

This returns a text file with both columns, I only want the second column.

Comment: I think need `usecols` parameter.

Comment: I can't seem to find such a parameter, there is "columns" parameter but that is also giving me an error.

Comment: I cannot see data, but `df_1  = pd.read_csv("result4.csv", usecols=[1])` should working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("test.csv").iloc[:, 1].to_csv("test1.csv", sep='\n', index=False)
```

You need to select only second column

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you